# python/scapy RandMAC() issue

Tags: python, scapy

I have a really annoying problem that I tried to solve for a few days.
I can't find any information on the net.

I tried to solve it myself, consulted with the documentations.
But nothing works.

My problem is

When I assign a variable `X` with `RandMAC()` function, `X` should be the same every time I use it.

Like,  `X = RandMAC()`, and let say `X` is now `AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF`
and when I print X for 3 times, it should be something like this.

```
X = AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF  
X = AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF  
X = AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

But what the code actually does is

```
X = AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF  
X = 00:0A:0B:0C:0D:0E:0F  
X = 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

So it changed every time I call print X.

How can I solve this issue ?

My code is as follow.

```
from scapy.all import *

X = RandMAC()

print X
print X
print X
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RandMAC` is a class, and when you call `RandMAC()` what you get is an instance of that class. `scapy` has a whole lot of these `RandXXXXX` classes, and they all behave in the same way: an instance of the class is really a sort of random-thing-generator, not a fixed (but randomly chosen) thing. In this instance, a `RandMac` is built out of six `RandByte`s, and a `RandByte` turns into a random value from 0 to 255 every time its value is asked for.

The idea, I think, is to make it easy to build (e.g.) an IP packet randomizer that gives you IP packets that are all the same except that a couple of fields are chosen at random for every packet.

So, anyway, many operations on random-thing objects are effectively delegated to the results of "fixing" them (i.e., picking a particular random value); see `volatile.py` in the source code, class `VolatileValue`; the magic happens in the `__getattr__` method. In particular, this applies to stringifying via `__str__`, which is what `str()` does as observed by Lycha and what `print` does as observed by Karun S.

If you want to get a single random value, the nearest thing to the Right Way is probably to call the `_fix` method: `X = RandMAC()._fix()`. That happens to be the same as `str` for `RandMAC`, but e.g. if you have a random integer then `_fix` will give you an actual integer while `str` will give you its string representation.

None of this appears to be documented. Don't make any large bets on it still working in future versions. (But, for what it's worth, `volatile.py` hasn't changed for about two years.)

Comment: Thank you very much, Gareth.
I'm really grateful for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `RandMac` has a way to do this other way, but you can convert the `X` into a string, that way it will stay the same. In your code `X` actually calls a function every time.

```
X = str(RandMAC())
print X
print X
print X
```